# racket hangs at sleep when racket/gui is imported

Tags: racket

On Linux and Racket v5.3, next program runs as expected,

```
#lang racket

(let loop ([i 0])
    (printf "~a\n" i)
    (sleep 0.01)
    (loop (add1 i)))
```

But this hangs after printing up to around 200,

```
#lang racket
(require racket/gui)

(let loop ([i 0])
    (printf "~a\n" i)
    (sleep 0.01)
    (loop (add1 i)))
```

This problem does not arise when running inside DrRacket.
Is this a bug or am I missing something? If a bug, is there a workaround?

Comment: FWIW this might be platform specific. The programs works for me in OS X.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a bug -- do you mind filing a bug report using the web page, or preferably using DrRacket?

Answer (score 2):

This has now been fixed in the latest development version, see [this commit](https://github.com/plt/racket/commit/6852140dd8f4d6c4d1abe41b25e4d8072b194901).